# Two different ways of expressing a stochastic integral?

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

> The question is to solve the 1-D SDE
>   $$
> dX_t = \mu_t X_t dt + \alpha_tX_tdB_t^1 + \beta_t X_t dB_t^2, \quad X_0 = x_0,
> $$
>   where $\mu, alpha$ and $\beta$ are (nice) deterministic functions and $B=(B^1,B^2)$ is a 2-D standard Brownian motion.

Down below is my way of expressing this Geometric Brownian motion (and the teacher's solution):
[image: My solution (and the second version)]

Isn't this the exact same way of expressing one and the same thing? Or am I missing something obvious that makes my way of expressing it incorrect by not using the integrals?

Best regards

Comment: your $\mu$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are potentially $t$-variant, albeit deterministic, so no not the same, eg your leftmost term only works for constant $\mu$

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, I think I see what you mean. Appreciate it!

That μ , α and β are considered to be "nice" doesn't change that fact? If μ , α and β would have been constants (no t as subscript), then the two expressions would be equal?

Comment: No problem! I think 'nice' generally means things like measurable / integrable, possibly 'smooth' (continuous and sufficiently differentiable etc..) but not as boring as constant :) If you got rid of the $t$-subscripts and took as them as constants then yes the 2 expressions are the same.

Comment: Fantastic (even if I gave the incorrect answer...), thanks once again!

(And regarding "nice", the things that you mention are exactly the ones brought up in the course so I believe that you are absolutely right).

Comment: No problem enjoy the course!